# Conflict between two images that begin with same letter

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a problem showing two images that begin with same letter, the first one showing well when i call the URL, but the second one redirect me to 404 error page ... notice that when i change the name of the second image to a different first letter, I get it showing normally.

Name of the two images I am using:

- tinyimg.png
- tosave.png

And I just wanted to show them on my webpage: `http://localhost/assets/img/tinyimg.png` or `http://localhost/assets/img/tosave.png`! The second one redirect to an error page 404.

This is the htaccess file I am using in my root directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks  
RewriteEngine On  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f  

RewriteRule ^/(css|js|img)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)?$ /$1/$2 [L,QSA,R=301]
```

Can you show me where the error is?

Comment: If you delete the image `tinyimg.png`, does `tosave.png` not 404?

Comment: @alexy13 Yes sir, if i delete `tinyimg.png`, the other image will work, and vice versa.

Comment: @S Triss So, the file that you add first works, and the subsequent ones don't? Interesting.

Comment: There a problem on my htaccess, it support only one image that begin with same letter in the same folder !!! Very annoying problem.

Comment: Can the problem two can come from cloudfalre ? notice that i already cleared the cache.

Comment: Do you have any custom rules in cloudflare on your cloudflare page when you login?

Comment: No nothing sir.